# Writing out of boundary matrix

Tags: c, memory, undefined-behavior

The exercise in an exam required writing on paper the values that the memory obtains after executing the following program. The issue is that in this program, we are accessing unallocated memory when the for loop reaches element 3. Whether the value written to unallocated memory is actually stored or is undefined behavior, and thus it is correct not to write it since we don't know what actually happens. Following the programm:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int k[5][7] = {0};
  int *p, *z;
 
  p = k[1];
  *p = 12;
 
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    z = p + 8;
    *z = *p + 2;
    p = z;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Running the program, I get a segmentation fault, but in the exam correction, the professor still assigned the value written in the unallocated memory area. So is it right to write on paper the value that we are writing to a unallocated memory ?

Comment: I'm not seeing the question

Comment: This code is ridiculously bad from the readability perspective. What is it supposed to demonstrate?

Comment: Writing beyond the array bounds is undefined behaviour. Thus is not correct not to write it, unless it's a demonstration of UB.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I know it is an exercise from my cs exam. I didn't write this code and i know that is wrong. But still my professor writed on paper the value on the unallocated memory.

Comment: @WeatherVane ye that is what i thought.

Comment: "What happens if I deliberately drive off the road?" Maybe nothing. Maybe something really bad. It's not something you want to do deliberately unless you know *exactly* what you're doing.

Comment: @tadman, yeah, I agree. That's why, in my opinion, it's not correct to write it. We don't know if all the tiers get punctured or if everything goes fine.

Comment: There are cases where writing "out of bounds" is perfectly acceptable, but it's under specific conditions. There are types of structures with an array at the end that's "zero" sized, but when allocating memory for this via `malloc` or equivalent an additional amount of memory is allocated to store a variable number of entries. In this case, because you're not exceeding the *allocation bounds*, the access is fine. When you write `char x[N]` you're in effect doing an allocation, and you're limited by the *allocation bounds*.

Comment: @tadman So in my case because we are doing an allocation like char x[N], we are limited to the allocation bounds.

Comment: Exactly. You'll often see that called "automatic" allocation in the C world, as in it just happens for you, versus "dynamic" where you need to explicitly do it. With automatic allocation you must respect the bounds or you'll create chaos. With dynamic allocation you have some flex *if* you allocate accordingly and know how arrays behave via things like *pointer decay*.

Comment: @tadman `int (*k)[7] = malloc(sizeof(int[5][7]); ... z = p + 8;` would still invoke undefined behavior if going through `k[1]` and thereby doing pointer arithmetic beyond 7 `int`. The storage doesn't matter there. _However_, `int (*k)[7] = malloc(sizeof(int[5][7]); int*p = (int*)k; p+=8;` would be different since the chunk returned from malloc has no effective type yet and so we can access it as if it was a plain 1D array. The standard rules fo strict aliasing/effective type are vaguely specified for array types in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rules for pointer arithmetic (including the use of `[]`) are specified in the C standard chapter for the additive operators (C17 6.5.6 §8). The most important part:

> If both the pointer operand and the result point
> to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object, the evaluation
> shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the behavior is undefined. If the result points one past
> the last element of the array object, it shall not be used as the operand of a unary * operator that is
> evaluated.

- `p` points at the array `k[1]`. For the above rules, it is not relevant that `k` is a multi-dimensional array.
- `p` is only allowed to do pointer arithmetic within the bounds of this array `k[1]`.
- As a special rule, `p` *is* allowed to do pointer arithmetic exactly 1 item past the end of the array. So  `p + 7` would be well-defined.
- But `p + 8` is undefined behavior.

Basically, the multi-dimensional array is guaranteed to be allocated adjacently in memory. There *is* a valid, allocated `int` location past the end of the inner array `k[1]`. But we may not calculate the address of that "past the end" item using pointer arithmetic based on a pointer pointing at `k[1]`. The pointer arithmetic itself may result in incorrect code getting generated since the compiler is free to assume that any access to `k[1]` through `p`/`z` will not change items in the array `k[2]`.

For example we could add this code to the end of the loop:

```c
if(k[2][1]==0)
  puts("zero");
```

And the compiler is then in theory free to replace it with a non-conditional `puts("zero")` since nothing in the code is allowed to change this array item.

The correct answer to your exam question is therefore: it is undefined behavior and anything can happen.

Answer (score 2):

> So is it right to write on paper the value that we are writing to a unallocated memory ?

The C language specification provides no justification for any particular answer to the question, on account of the multiple undefined behaviors exercised by the program.

But that's not directly relevant, because it is your professor who decides what answers they will accept.  Possibly they would accept an answer explaining why the behavior is undefined instead of giving the memory layout requested, but it is more likely that they expect you to assume some particular behavior and answer based on that.

I don't have much regard for such a question, but if I were faced with it then I would probably do all of the above: explain the undefined behaviors involved, then describe a particular, reasonable choice of behavior on which to base an answer about the resulting contents of memory, and then give the answer implied by that behavior.  That covers all the bases.